# Setting default at some port be some specific web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

currently I am running my web service from following path

```
http://localhost:16022/MachineService.asmx
```

and usage of some web method like

```
http://localhost:16022/MachineService.asmx?op=GetData1
```

I want to do it in following way

to run the web service from following path

```
http://localhost:16022/
```

and usage of some web method like

```
http://localhost:16022?op=GetData1
```

Is it possible to set it be the default ?

I am using VS2010.
Also possible to do so at the IIS7 itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`defaultDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690361%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Element in your web.config file so you won't have to specify `MachineService.asmx` with each and every call.

```
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="MachineService.asmx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Instead of manually modifying web.config you can configure the default document in *Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager*.